# How can I generate getter and setter in vscode python automatically for private variable

Tags: python

This is my class called manager I want to generate automatically getter and setter in python vs code.

```
class Manager:
    def __init__(self, name, salary, bonus):
        self.bonus = bonus
        self.__salary = salary
        self.name = name
    def show_info(self):
        print("Name: ", self.name)
        print("Salary: ", self.__salary)
        print("Bonus: ", self.bonus)
    
    def give_bonus(self):
        print("You have received a bonus of ", self.bonus)

manager = Manager("Kamran", 10000, 5000)
manager.show_info()
manager.give_bonus()
```

Comment: If you're just going to generate getters and setters, you have no reason to make this thing private in the first place.

Comment: Setters and getters are considered an  anti-pattern in Python, if really needed use a property. And there are no private attributes, there's only a conversion to handle underscore attributes privately. Please try not to bring Java patterns into Python!

Comment: Which syntax is used to achieve getters and setters in python syntax  can you explain it.